# React Router V6: prevent user from accessing children routes directly and redirect to parent route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have my routes setup like this:

```js
<Route path={`/home`} element={<PrivateRoute />}>
    <Route
        index={true}
        element={<Home />}
    />
    <Route path={`settings`} element={<Settings />} />
</Route>
```

Here, I want to redirect the user back to the root (`/home`) when the user has opened `/home/settings` directly from the browser. That is, I do not want the user to open any of the children routes before opening the parent route.

Note: This does not have to do anything with authentication.

This is what I've tried:
In `PrivateRoute` component, I've used a context to store the pathnames that the user has visited. And each time a page is opened, I check if the `/home` path exists. If it doesn't, I route the user to `/home`.
But I feel this is extremely bad for code maintainability and also might not be the right way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this use case? Can you [edit] the post to include an attempt and details on any issues you face?

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the question with what I've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing and checking all the paths a user has visited you could just store a boolean state of the `"/home"` path has been visited. I'd suggest using a couple layout routes, one to provide a `homeVisited` state and a callback to update the state. One layout route provides the context while the other layout handles the redirection to `"/home"` if it has not been visited yet.

Example:

```
const HomeCheckProviderLayout = () => {
  const [visited, setVisited] = React.useState();

  const visitedHome = () => setVisited(true);

  return <Outlet context={{ visited, visitedHome }} />;
};

const HomeCheckLayout = () => {
  const { visited } = useOutletContext();

  return visited ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/home" replace />;
};
```

The `Home` component uses the `useOutletContext` hook to access the `visitedHome` to trigger in a `useEffect` hook.

```
const Home = () => {
  const { visitedHome } = useOutletContext();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    visitedHome();
  }, [visitedHome]);

  ....
};
```

Routing configuration:

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
    <Route path="/home" element={<HomeCheckProviderLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route element={<HomeCheckLayout />}>
        <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />
        ... other routes that should redirect to `"/home"` if unvisited yet ...
      </Route>
    </Route>
    ... other protected routes ...
  </Route>
  ... other routes ...
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-prevent-user-from-accessing-children-routes-directly-and-redire]